# $S_x$ and $S_y$ states for spin 1

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, linear-algebra

I asked a question earlier but it looks like I misunderstood something [Convert eigenvectors to different basis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/676618/).  I'm considering the case of a spin 1 object, where the eigenvalues of $S_z$ are 1,0,-1 so the $S_z$ diagonal basis is just {|1⟩,|0⟩,|−1⟩} and from this we can just write the $S_z$ operator as

$$S_z = \hbar \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$

In most text, the discussion for the expression of the $S_x$ and $S_y$ states in terms of the $S_z$ basis is discussed only for a spin-$1/2$ system. How do I do this for spin-1?

Comment: Just write the matrix expression for $S_y$ or $S_x$ and diagonalize…. you will get the eigenstates as combo of the $S_z$ eigenstates.

Comment: I answered this for spin-3/2 here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607218/

Answer (score 1):

Like all angular momentum operators
the spin-$1$ operators ($S_x,S_y,S_z$) need to satisfy
the commutator relations:

$$\begin{align}
[S_x,S_y]&=i\hbar S_z \\
[S_y,S_z]&=i\hbar S_x \\
[S_z,S_x]&=i\hbar S_y
\end{align}$$

Given the matrix for $S_z$ you can find
matrices for $S_x$ and $S_y$, so that
all these commutator relations are satisfied
(see for example [Spin operators and matrices](https://easyspin.org/easyspin/documentation/spinoperators.html)).

$$S_x = \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$S_y = \frac{\hbar}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{bmatrix}0&-i&0\\i&0&-i\\0&i&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: and then the eigenstates of Sx and Sy in the Sz basis are just the eigenvectors of those matrices?

Comment: @jboy Yes, correct.

Comment: thanks! just as clarification, the result I would get would be different for Sx in the Sx diagonal basis right? (which is also something I still cant figure out)

Comment: @jboy Yes, all 3 matrices would be different. $S_x$ would be diagonal., and $S_y$ and $S_z$ would be non-diagonal.

Comment: How would I find $S_x$ in the $S_x$ diagonal basis? Would it be as if it were the $S_z$ that is the eigenstates are 1, 0, -1?

Comment: @jboy yes, correct